# Chrome extension: debug content script before packaging

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension. It sets/reads local storage, reads the DOM, and sends an Ajax message. But sometimes it never reaches the server and I don't know where it gets stuck. Reloading the page doesn't work, although the extension works if I load another page in the same tab, and the original page will work if I load it in another tab. I use activeTab permission.

How can I debug this? The Chrome tutorial http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging.html only mentions a popup, which I do not have. (I right-click the icon and "Inspect popup" is not visible.)

I have tried plain old F12/sources, but I don't see my extension there, even when it works.

I am on localhost and the extension is not packaged. I am still working in developer mode.

Comment: You can find it in developer tools>Sources>Content scripts>{Your id}

Comment: It's not packaged so I haven't got an ID. It's not there. Maybe I need to package it?

Comment: No, it always has an id.

Comment: Not mine :( I wrote an answer below - seems it shows up under programs, not content script. Guessing because it isn't packaged, just in developer mode.

Comment: I assure you that it both has an ID and will show up under content scripts. On the extensions page when you load it in it will tell you the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension does not show up in developer tools>Sources>Content scripts, maybe because it isn't packaged. I can see the content script from another regular extension.

To see mine I:

Wrote the following  as the first line in my script:

```
debugger;
```

Before pressing the extension icon, I bring up the developer tools: F12

Now, when I click the extension icon, my script opens under sources/program. It does not do this if the developer tools is not open.